# Play pause button not working on tab to tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, node.js

I am trying to build a function with jquery but I can't. I am trying to control video and audio with one button set for the different tabs. the problem is that the play pause button only controls the audio file not the video file in the second tab.

when we go to the second tab and press the button below it plays the same audio file.

see the sample code here

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#audio_play").on("click", function () {
                $("#audio").get(0).play();
            })
            $("#audio_pause").on("click", function () {
                $("#audio").get(0).pause();
            })
            $('.menu ul li:nth(1)').on("click", function () {

                $("#audio_play").attr('id', 'video_play');
                $("#audio_pause").attr('id', 'video_pause');

            })
            $("#video_play").on("click", function () {
                $("#video").get(0).play();
            })
            $("#video_pause").on("click", function () {
                $("#video").get(0).pause();
            })
        })
```

```css
.con{
 text-align:center;
 width:156px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.8.2/alpine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex justify-center items-center w-full h-screen inset-x-0 mx-auto">
        <!--actual component start-->
        <div class="menu" x-data="setup()">
            <ul class="flex justify-center items-center my-4">
                <template x-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :key="index">
                    <li class="cursor-pointer py-2 px-4 text-gray-500 border-b-8"
                        :class="activeTab===index ? 'text-green-500 border-green-500' : ''" @click="activeTab = index"
                        x-text="tab"></li>
                </template>
            </ul>

            <div class="w-full bg-white p-16 text-center mx-auto border">
                <div x-show="activeTab===0">
                <h1>Audio Player</h1>
                    <audio id="audio"
                        src="https://res.cloudinary.com/foxyplays989/video/upload/v1558369838/LetsGo.mp3"></audio>
                </div>
                <div x-show="activeTab===1">
                <iframe id="video" class="w-full h-56"
                                            src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?loop=false&amp;byline=false&amp;portrait=false&amp;title=false&amp;speed=true&amp;transparent=0&amp;gesture=media"
                                            allowfullscreen allowtransparency allow="autoplay"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div x-show="activeTab===2">Content 3</div>
                <div x-show="activeTab===3">Content 4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--actual component end-->
    </div>
        <div class="flex con">
            <button class="inline-block px-6 py-2 text-xs font-medium leading-6 text-center text-white uppercase transition bg-blue-700 rounded shadow ripple hover:shadow-lg hover:bg-blue-800 focus:outline-none" id="audio_play">play</button>
            <button class="inline-block px-6 py-2 text-xs font-medium leading-6 text-center text-white uppercase transition bg-red-500 rounded shadow ripple hover:shadow-lg hover:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none" id="audio_pause">Pause</button>
        </div>
    <script>
        function setup() {
            return {
                activeTab: 0,
                tabs: [
                    "Tab No.1",
                    "Tab No.2",
                ]
            };
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: no one is there to help me.

Comment: 1) Your video is a Vimeo iframe so you can't use the standard `play()` and `pause()` methods to control it. Look into the Vimeo Player SDK for proper implementation on how to be able to control the Vimeo player with Javascript: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/basics

2) You're setting the event listeners on the video buttons before they even exist. Either add a separate set of video buttons into the HTML, or move the click event listeners for the video buttons into the menu click listener (personally, I'd do the former).